# Commutative algebra - prove that domain with other requirement gives field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $A$ be a domain. Assume that for any non-trivial finitely generated $A$-module $M$ we have $\operatorname{Hom}_A(M, A)\neq \{0\}$.
Prove that $A$ is a field.

It seems easy but I haven't found solution yet. 
Any hints?

Comment: Your question is improved a lot with some trivial typesetting. I invite you to check the edit log to see how it was done so you can do it yourself in the future.

Comment: Thanks a lot @rschwieb , I promise I will learn MathJax before Christmas. Now I have partial exam tomorrow and speeches on seminaris, hard weeks.

Answer (score 3):

Let $a\in A$, $a\ne0$, and take $f\colon A/(a)\to A$ nonzero, assuming $a$ is not invertible.

In particular, $b=f(1+(a))\ne0$ (prove it).

What can you say about $ab$?

Comment: a*b=a*f(1+(a))=f(a+a*(a))=f(0+(a))=0 so a and b are non zero zero divisord. Thanks a lot, it was really easy but sometimes we can;t do easier things and can harder. Have a nice day.

Comment: @MaciejFicek $af(1+(a))=f(a(1+(a))=f(a+(a))=f(0+(a))=0$. It’s wrong to write $x(y+I)=xy+xI$.

Comment: a*(a) belongs to ideal (a) so I did not write a false, I've just write too much, too formal.

Comment: @MaciejFicek It's not “too formal”: $xy+xI$ is generally not a member of $A/I$, because the ideal $xI$ is generally *smaller* than $I$.